# how to view the stored procedure code in MSSQl Server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

how to view the stored procedure code in MSSQl Server management studio

Comment: Make an effort. That application has an entire GUI devoted to list, manipulating, examining, modifying objects in a database. You can easily find tutorials for using SSMS - like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_sql_server/ms_sql_server_management_studio.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_helptext` stored procedure if You have sufficient rights.
You may also want to assign a shortcut to it in Management Studio options.

```sql
-- EXEC sp_helptext 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME'

EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_who'
```